# CollectionView Cell images are changing

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

In `cellForItemAt indexPath` I call:

```
if cell.venueImageView.image == nil {
    cell.loadImage(imageURL: venue.imageURL)
}
```

`loadImage` function is in `UICollectionViewCell` class:

```
func loadImage(imageURL: String) {
    print("LOAD IMAGE: \(imageURL)")
    Alamofire.request("http://***/" + imageURL).responseImage { response in
        if let image = response.result.value {
            self.venueImageView.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

For the first time it shows correct images, but then when I scroll  down then up, first image appears in second cell and second image appears in first cell and so on. What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement this method inside your UICollectionViewCell:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    venueImageView.image = nil
}
```

This gets called every time before a cell gets reused.
Also you should try to store your downloaded image. Otherwise the image has to be loaded every time you scroll.

To clarify: Your cell gets reused when scrolled off screen to avoid memory leaks. That means that your downloaded image also gets deleted. The next time you scroll to the cell, the image is gone and has to be downloaded again.

If I were you I would store all the downloaded images inside an array in your ViewController and set the image in `cellForItemAt indexPath` with `cell.venueImageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]`.